# Discord Py Need to give my bot role silently in background

Tags: python, discord.py

I still have not figured out how to add/remove roles on the bot itself, without executing commands in the chat. It has to be silently in the background. Can someone please help me.

Current code below that does work but not the way I want it to. I do not want the bot to type a command to give itself a role, I need it to automatically give it silently without any chat messages being executed. My ideal idea is to execute the addRole function in the on_ready event somehow, without sending message to get a role.

```
import aiohttp
from datetime import datetime
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import os

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    bot.session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    await bot.get_channel(402353715718277809).send("$addRole")

@bot.command()
async def addRole(ctx):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="market_green")
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(bot.user.id)
    await member.add_roles(role)


bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guild` object in discord.py has a `.me` attribute [(docs)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.me) which represents yourself in that guild.

So on start you can get that guild based on it's id (in the on_ready event) and assign yourself a role with add_roles, example code(with guildid the id of the guild you want the role in):

```
guild = bot.get_guild(guildid)
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="market_green")
await guild.me.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yesterday I got told it's impossible in on_ready, but this works. Thank you, just had to remove "await" from line 1.

Comment: Yeah right, get_guild isnt asynchronous, fetch_guild is... a bit of a facepalm on my part. I've edited it anyways for further clarity if anyone needs it later